# I can't find what's wrong with my javascript-ajax-php "upload file" code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

this is my first question here (usually I like to find my own ways to solve problems) but I just can't find problem in my file upload code. It's supposed to use AJAX. I simplified everything so it would be easier for you to read. Here is HTML form:

```
<form id="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="php/uploadfile.php">
<p>Insert file: <input type="file" id="fileUp" name="fileUp" />
<button type="submit" id="uploadButton" onclick="sendFile();">Upload</button></p>
</form>
```

Now here goes javascript **sendFile()** function:

```
function sendFile()
{    
    var forma = document.getElementById("fileForm");
    var failas = document.getElementById("fileUp");
    var uploadButton = document.getElementById("uploadButton");

    forma.onsubmit = function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    uploadButton.innerHTML = "Uploading, please wait!";

    var newFile = failas.files[0];

    var formData = new FormData(forma);
    formData.append("fileUp", newFile, newFile.name);

    alert(newFile.name);// Here it says filename.jpg it means everything is ok at this stage

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/uploadfile.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

And php:

```
<?php
echo var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

It should alert contents of $_FILES, but it says array(0){} even if I try $_REQUEST. So, if anyone could suggest what may be wrong, it would be appreciated :]

Comment: Sidenote: `var_dump($_FILES);` and not `echo var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: Plus, your script should have a function called `sendFile()` which is not posted in your code. I.e.: `function sendFile()` being called by `onclick="sendFile();`

Comment: No, echo is needed because it is returned as AJAX responseText, and then I can alert it with javascript ;)

Comment: sorry, i didn't paste function sendFile(), will fix that, but it exists in my script

Comment: standard ajax cannot do uploads. ESPECIALLY when you give the ajax code the incorrect mime type. you have (properly) `multipart/form-data` in your actual form, then use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the ajax call.

Comment: Hmm, i tried changing that to multipart/form-data, but it's still the same, javascript alerts array(0){}

Comment: but really? standart ajax can't do this?

Comment: Not sure what "standard ajax" means.  Anyway, this is possible in all browsers other than IE9 and older.  Also, the enctype is irrelevant when you are using FormData to upload via XHR.  Definitely do not set the content-type in your request.  The browser will set it for you.

Comment: I understood "standart ajax" as ajax without jquery, but i'm not sure if that's the real meaning :)

Comment: It likely means everything other than XHR2 (that is, IE9 and older).  jQuery delegates to `XMLHttpRequest` when sending ajax requests.  If XHR can't upload files, then neither can jQuery

Comment: @AMD_Paulius `echo` is **never** needed with `var_dump($_FILES)`, even with Ajax.

Comment: Try this for Ajax file upload - http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/. No need to reinvent the wheel when someone's already done it for you.

Comment: You are right, i'm new to ajax and i thought that echo is always needed to get responseText. But it's extreme curiosity that's driving me to reinvent this wheel, so i'm still waiting for an answer!

Comment: ...Or if you want an upload library with more features that is actively developed, look at http://fineuploader.com.

Comment: Why not use '$_POST[]' instead of REQUEST or FILE in your PHP?

Comment: But I tried $_POST[] too, it's all the same :(